# Easy68k. How can i use the index correctly in a loop?

Tags: assembly, easy68k

```
ORG $400400
COUNT   DC.B 4
NUM1    DC.B $4E,$57,$29,$5A,$3B  
NUM2    DC.B $31,$D4,$55,$E0,$9B


       ORG $400410
SUBRTN MOVE.B $400401,D0
   LEA $400405,A0
   LEA $400410,A1
LOOP
   ADDX -(A0),-(A1)
   DBRA D0,LOOP
      END $400410
```

So i have this code, and i want use an index (A0) at the end of of my nums1 (offset $400405),and an index (A1) at the end of my nums 2 (offset $400410), i want to create a loop that adds the indexes (ADDX -(A0),-(A1)) and store the add result to the end of my nums2 in descending order ($400405,$400404,$400403 etc.)

Also i think that i need to use DBRA for my 5 loops but im kinda stuck cause i lack experiance on programming on the 68k

Note: Running this code gives me the error "Address Error: Instruction at 400422 accessing address 400403"

Comment: Your counter is at `400400` not `400401`. Also you got the end of both arrays wrong. You can avoid these mistakes by using the labels you defined. Loading a byte will not zero the top bits. Furthermore `ADDX` without a suffix is probably not a byte size operation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `ADDX` without a qualifier is doing `ADDX.L` (or `ADDX.W`).  Try writing `ADDX.B` instead.

It is possible that `ADDX.B` won't be accepted by the assembler, as various online texts seem to disagree as to whether ADDX.B exists.  (There appears to be an encoding for it in the machine code, though.)

The address $400403 comes because the processor is pre-decrementing `A0`, which holds $400405, by 2 bytes to access a 16-bit word (possibly as part of the 2 word accesses necessary on the 16-bit bus to fetch a longword).  Odd addresses cannot be used with 16-bit data or 32-bit data in (most if not all of) the MC68k family of processors, hence the exception.

From http://www.tigernt.com/onlineDoc/68000.pdf :

> > The ADDX instruction is used in chain arithmetic to add together
> >     strings of bytes (words or longwords). Consider the addition of
> >     two 128-bit numbers, each of which is stored as four consecutive
> >     longwords.
> >
> > ```
> >     LEA Number1,A0 A0 points at first number
> >     LEA Number2,A1 A1 points at second number
> >     MOVEQ #3,D0 Four longwords to add
> >     MOVE #$00,CCR Clear X-bit and Z-bit of the CCR
> > LOOP
> >     ADDX -(A0),-(A1) Add pair of numbers
> >     DBRA D0,LOOP Repeat until all added
> > ```

Let's make some observations:

1. Unadorned `ADDX` is being used to perform 32-bit arithmetic.
2. `DBRA D0, LOOP` decrements 16-bit register `d0.w` — but you are loading a byte into `d0.b`, meaning the upper 8 bits of `d0.w` are technically undefined (though the simulator may have started all the registers as initially zero).  The `moveq` instruction they are using initializes the full 32-bit register, `d0.l`.
3. You are loading the value $4E into `d0.b` (instead of 4) because you have an off by 1 error in the address.
4. The above sample uses `move #$00, CCR` to positively clear the `X`-bit before the start of the loop that uses extended arithmetic via `ADDX`.

Comment: Thanks you for well informed reply Erik. I appreciate it a lot! :)

Comment: Convention is that when size isn't specified, it defaults to word (.w) - most assemblers, if not all, follow this.